# Which specification does the statsmodels ARIMA use?

Tags: time-series, arima, statsmodels

I am estimating a model with exogenous variables using `ARIMA`, from the `statsmodels` package. But I can't interpret the results, the coefficients are very different from what I expected. Consider the following model:

$$
y_t = 1 + 0.5 y_{t-1} + 4 z_t + \varepsilon_t
$$

where $z_t$ is a dummy and exogenous variable. I've simulated the model using the following code:

```py
np.random.seed(42)
c = 1
fi = 0.5
sig = 1
d = 4
y = [2]
n = 1000
z = [0, 1] * int(n/2)
for i in range(n):
    y.append(c + fi*y[i] + d*z[i] + np.random.normal(scale=sig))
y = pd.Series(y[1:])
df = pd.DataFrame({'y': y, 'z': z}) 
m = ARIMA(df['y'], exog=df[['z']], order=(1, 0, 0)).fit()
m.summary()
```

The output is:

```
const     4.686270
z         2.689766
ar.L1     0.494128
sigma2    0.960973
dtype: float64
```

The estimated value for the coefficient of $y_{t-1}$ is OK. But the values for the constant and for the coefficient of $z_t$ is very different from what I expected. Estimating the model using OLS gives a very different result:

```py
df['y_lag'] = df['y'].shift(1)
df = df.dropna()
X = sm.add_constant(df[['y_lag', 'z']])
m2 = sm.OLS(df['y'], X).fit()
m2.params
```

```
const    1.058504
y_lag    0.492424
z        4.012447
dtype: float64
```

That is, the values for the coefficient of $y_{t-1}$ are very similar, but the values for constant and the coefficient of $z_t$ are differents. Probably the `ARIMA` estimates the model using a different parameterization.

My two questions are:

1. In an ARMA(p, q) with exogenous variables, what parameterization does `ARIMA` use in the estimation?
2. In a model like
   $$
   y_t = c + \phi_1 y_{t-1} + \cdots + \phi_p y_{t-p} + d_1 z_{1, t} + d_2 Z_{2,t} + \cdots + d_k z_{k, t} + \varepsilon_t
   $$

how can I calculate the $d_j$ parameters from the `ARIMA` output?